# Check for write caching enabled or not on Linux

Tags: linux, ide, filesystems, linux-kernel, data-storage

I want to check if the write-caching is enabled or not for my IDE drive on Linux... How do I do it ?

Comment: Try here: http://superuser.com/questions/160185/turn-off-linux-file-cache/163928#163928

Answer (score 4):

Run `/sbin/hdparm -I` as `root`, write caching is enabled if there is a `*` next to `Write cache`.